# Mono: Can no longer set X509Certificate2 Private key using settor

Tags: c#, .net, mono, x509certificate2

Sometime in the recent past Mono struck out support for setting a private key on an X509Certificate2. Version 6.8.0.96 results in **Platform Not Supported** exception.

I need to do this as I have been given a pair of pem cert and rsa key files that I read and reassemble into an X509Certificate2. This worked in the past.

So I read that the advised way of setting the Private key for both .NET Framework and .NET Core is with this extension 'CopyWithPrivateKey'. https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/14152#issuecomment-499524798

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.copywithprivatekey?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_RSACertificateExtensions_CopyWithPrivateKey_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_

Project is .NET framework 4.7.2 that this extension is supposedly provided for. It was not available in 4.7.1.

Amending the code to use CopyWithPrivateKey results in **X509Certificate2' does not contain a definition for 'CopyWithPrivateKey'**

The namespace as specified (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates) is included. Yet no dice. There is no obvious suggestion from Visual Studio to add a reference for any particular assembly. It doesn't look like a nuget package.

What's going on? Is this supported or not? Why was it stripped out of the Mono codebase in such a manner? Was there no concern for backwards compatibility?

Has anyone had to figure out a workaround for this?

Comment: "Was there no concern for backwards compatibility?" As Mono/.NET Core will converge to .NET 5, breaking changes like this can be inevitable. What's the reason to use Mono today?

Comment: Saves a rewrite of a large code base - something I've been planning on but not something I can do in the next week which is the timeframe I'm stuck with.. Either way - why can't I find 'CopyWithPrivateKey' in System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates for 4.7.2?

Comment: Is your key typed as AsymmetricAlgorithm?  The CopyWithPrivateKey extension methods all require a key typed as RSA, DSA, or ECDsa.  (They're defined on types called RSACertificateExtensions, DSACertificateExtensions, and ECDsaCertificateExtensions).

Comment: @bartonjs Yeah it's an RSA key. But the CopyWithPrivateKey extension method is just not available on the X509Certificate2 instance. I'm obviously missing something.